# Observables core part of Javascript

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular2-observables

Was trying to research if Observables from [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/) are going to be a core part of JS. However I could not find any clear information of this. Are they going to be core Javascript APIs in the future?

Comment: There is an effort to get [observable support into browsers](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/544) that's independent of the TC39 proposal. And that issue contains [a comment that you might find interesting](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/544#issuecomment-351607779); the comment describes the timeline to date of the TC39 observable proposal mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Observables](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable) are currently in the [proposal stage](https://github.com/tc39/proposals). It hasn't yet been presented to the TC39 committee, so it's not yet known if they will be a part of ECMAScript in the future.

Comment: They are not part of the ES7? Please, [read this](https://derickbailey.com/2017/06/06/3-features-of-es7-and-beyond-that-you-should-be-using-now/), because there its mentioned the use of observables.

Comment: @robe007 No, they aren't part of ES7 (yet), but they're so popular that the post is treating them like they're already officially done. Most people use the RxJS library for Observables.

Comment: Mmmm, interesting. Thanks for that clarification !